# How can I change IE's homepage without opening IE?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, windows-server-2008

Here's an interesting problem. On a recently installed Server 2008 64bit I opened IE and through the Tools -> Options I changed the homepage to iGoogle.com. Clicked okay and then clicked the homepage button. IE crashes.

Now you'd think that I could just remove iGoogle as the homepage but when I open IE it immediately goes to that page and crashes on open.

Obviously I'd prefer to find a solution to why IE is crashing on the iGoogle page but just to get IE running again I need to remove iGoogle as the homepage. Is there anyway to do this without opening IE?

Comment: A downvoted because I don't see this as a software programmer question, but a general computer support issue.

Of course, if others disagree with me, they'll vote it back up.  Viva la democracy!

Comment: Kudos Jay Bazuzi for giving a reason for a down vote! I just upvoted your down vote reason.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Control Panel -> Internet Options

Comment: LOL I guess thats how it goes.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the registry, the start page seems to be stored in

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Start Page

Comment: This seems to be the most complicated way to go about it.

Comment: This is the best answer because you can modified by programming... if it's not a programming way than this should be close ;)

Answer (score 4):

You could do it through the control panel, but you could also supply a url as a parameter to iexplore.exe.

```
start » run » iexplore about:blank
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Control Panel->Internet Options
2. Start->Run... "%windir%\system32\inetcpl.cpl"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about IE7 on Windows Server 2008, but for IE6 the start page is stored in a registry key "Start Page" in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is posted, but here's how you can discover the answer without having to ask 
 1: Set the homepage to something random ie FindMeKeyForURL.com

 2: Search the registry for it

 3: Extract it out and modify it, now you can deploy the .reg file